# How do I pivot/turn a table so that each row becomes a set of columns in the new table?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have to say this question is hard to phrase.

So, here is what I have - a table(TAX_A, TAX_B... are not constants; the number of records is practically limited to 4, but can be as little as none, in which case the 8 columns should have NULL values):

```
tax_name        tax_amount
TAX_A              58.39 
TAX_B              151.81
TAX_C              78.00 
...
```

and this is what the end result should look like:

```
tax_name1  tax_amount1  tax_name2  tax_amount2  tax_name2  tax_amount2
    TAX_A      58.39        TAX_B      151.81       TAX_C      78.00
```

I was thinking to use a PIVOT at first, but then I am not sure how to deal with the second column as I want to move the values in pairs(name, amount).

Please, advise. How can it be done in SQL?

Answer (score 1):

It's a called a table rotation. You need to know the number of columns in the result set.

Given your table specification, the following will work:

```
select tax_name1 = t1.tax_name , tax_amount1 = t1.tax_amount ,
       tax_name2 = t2.tax_name , tax_amount2 = t2.tax_amount ,
       tax_name3 = t3.tax_name , tax_amount3 = t3.tax_amount ,
       tax_name4 = t4.tax_name , tax_amount4 = t4.tax_amount
from      foo  t1
full join foo  t2 on t2.tax_name = 'TAX_B'
full join foo  t3 on t3.tax_name = 'TAX_C'
full join foo  t4 on t4.tax_name = 'TAX_D'
where t1.tax_name = 'TAX_A'
```

In a more "real world" scenario, the first table would be to select the distinct set of identifiers for the rows you want in the result set, and then do left self-joins against each "iteration", something like:

```
select t.id ,
       tax_name1 = t1.tax_name , tax_amount1 = t1.tax_amount ,
       tax_name2 = t2.tax_name , tax_amount2 = t2.tax_amount ,
       tax_name3 = t3.tax_name , tax_amount3 = t3.tax_amount ,
       tax_name4 = t4.tax_name , tax_amount4 = t4.tax_amount
from (select distinct id from foo ) t
left join foo  t1 on t1.id = t.id and t1.tax_name = 'TAX_A'
left join foo  t2 on t2.id = t.id and t2.tax_name = 'TAX_B'
left join foo  t3 on t3.id = t.id and t3.tax_name = 'TAX_C'
left join foo  t4 on t4.id = t.id and t4.tax_name = 'TAX_D'
```

Cheers!

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear enough. TAX_A, TAX_B... are not constants. It is just the set of practically limited to 4, but the values differ. (this is subquery of much larger one).

Comment: It's OK if they're not constant values: you just need a way to filter each self-join so as to only include the desired rows for that self-join. Another approach that sometimes works is to use `GROUP BY` with an aggregate function for each column, containing around `case` expressions that distinguish the values for each column. In either case, you still need a way to map row identity to column identity.